# Android and back to main activity when time is up

Tags: android, android-activity, kill

I start a new activity from my main activity with

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Game.class);
startActivity(i);
```

The game activity has a timer which counts down to 0. I would like to pop back to the main activity (killing the game activity).

How do I enact this?

(I've already defined `onDestroy()` etc. correctly in my game activity.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method that gets called when the timer is up call finish()

Comment: @gngr44: Thanks for this. This is a smooth thing to do?

Comment: Yes. it is a smooth thing to do.

Comment: I still have some confusion. Do I need to call something like `setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity);` in the `onDestroy()` method of my game activity? When I call `finish()` in the game activity at time up nothing happens. (I'd like to pop back to the main activity, which was showing a main menu before starting the game.)

Comment: Are you saying you never called setContentView in the onCreate of your Game activity? finish() should go back to the previous activity (pressing the back button calls finish() by default).  Are you calling finish in the main thread?  That's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: I'm calling `setContentView` in `onCreate`of the main activity. When I call `finish()` in the game activity not a lot is happening. I'll keep trying.